# how to get location updates for every 6 secs using service in android

Tags: android, service, fusedlocationproviderapi

hi i am doing an app which send user location to server for every 6 secs using fused locationapi inside service.the problem is that i don't know how to schedule it to make it run for every 6 secs.i am newbie to android.so anybody help me.Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use AlarmManager or JobScheduler - for more info refer: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html look for their tutorial and implement using any one of the two. After implementing in case you face any issue then post it in here.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using rxJava library - it is very convenient:

```
Subscription repeatingTask = 
Observable.interval(6, Timeunit.SECONDS)
// receive notification on background thead
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.map( t -> {
  // do your work;
 return result;
}
.map(result -> {
 sendResult();
return result
})
// notify UI
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread)
.subscribe(r -> {
 // update UI
});

// unsubscribe when polling is no longer needed:
if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()){
   subscription.unsubscribe();
   subscription = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by creating a `foregroundService`. This might solve your problem of your service getting killed on low memory. A foreground service

> is a service that the user is actively aware of and is not a candidate
>   for the system to kill when low on memory. [Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

For a good examples of a foreground Service read through this thread: [Android - implementing startForeground for a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397754/android-implementing-startforeground-for-a-service)

Also to be informed when the location changes check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8600896/5183341

---

I also created a similar service than you are trying to do and allways had problems with my service getting killed on some devices. (Like the LG2 with API19). I tryed alot of different solotions like using an alarmmanager which restarts the service and so on. The only which worked  solid on all devices was using a foregroundService.