# Android requestLocationUpdates not called properly

Tags: android, gps, position

I would like to locate the user by clicking on a button. Therefore I use this code:

```
lm = getSystemService(LocationManager.class);
provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
listener = new LocationListener() {
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   Log.e("UPDATE","UPDATING LOCATION");
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
};

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
```

The requestLocationUpdates method is called but the onLocationChanged method is only called a few times. GPS is activated and the permissions are granted.

Do you have any idea why onLocationChanged is not always called? I also checked getLastKnownLocation which is sometimes false after calling requestLocationUpdates.

Comment: Check what it says in here to see if it helps somehow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8600896/3965050

Comment: I tried to register the listener inside requestLocationUpdates. Now it is never called. LocationManager is also checked (it is not null).

Comment: no, but what i meant is this part: onLocationChanged() will be called if the current location update is not matching with last known location.

Comment: But if I set distance to 0, it should be called with the same location.

Comment: and if you put a time instead of 0? still nothing? like 1000?

Comment: I mean, there are several [things to consider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Comment: Added my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think `onLocationChanged()` is not suppose to be called always, it will only be called if a location changes.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the request method to `lm.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, listener,null);` which works perfect as well as requestLocationUpdates with criteria.

Seems to be a problem with the provider.